# How can we move a scrollView object like history display in safari?

Tags: iphone, carousel

On touch move I want to slide my pictures like iphone music player changes its album in landscape mode.Or safari history pages changes by scrolling mouse.

Just want to know on touch move on iphone music player in landscape mode causes album to change by sliding one another together left to right and right to left.Do not want to use iCarousel.Want sliding animation that it applies by positioning z-index of views.

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: by using carosel you can achieve this one.

Comment: yes I am using my own made carousel and want animation code that applies on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a sample. Download source [here](http://code4app.com/down/id/4f7ff13c06f6e75f78000000). Hope this helps.